# Como inserir $_POST em input de formulário HTML?

Tags: php, html, formulário

Como inserir um `$_POST` em um `input` de um formulário `HTML`?
Em um formulário simples de login, ao deixar um campo em branco, o script resgata o campo preenchido, o mantém preenchido, e informa o erro do campo vazio, para que o usuário não tenha que digitar novamente.

Há uma forma de fazer isso com `PHP`, sem `Javascript`?
Basicamente o script receberia o `$_POST` enviado e preencheria o campo respectivo.

Só falta o script de inserção mesmo.

```js
<?php
function checkUsername($username)
{
 if ($username == "")
 {
  echo "<span style='color:red'>Preencha o campo Username!</span><br>";
 }
}

function checkPassword($password)
{
 if ($password == "")
 {
  echo "<span style='color:red'>Preencha o campo Password!</span><br>";
 }
}
```

```html
<?php
include 'includes/functions.php';

$check = false;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
 checkUsername($_POST['username']);
 checkPassword($_POST['password']);
 $check = true;
}
?>

<!-- FORMULÁRIO DE LOGIN -->
<div id="form">
 <form action="" method="post">
  <div class="_100">
   <label for="username">Username: </label><br>
   <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="">
   <label for="password">Password: </label><br>
   <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="*******"><br>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class=""> 
   <input type="submit" value="Entrar no Sistema">
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
<!-- /FORMULÁRIO DE LOGIN -->
```

Comment: Adicione a **formatação** no  `HTML`, `PHP`, `Javascript` e `$_POST` pra ficar mais organizado, minha edição conflitou com a sua...

Comment: @Florida obrigado. Desta forma que está agora?

Comment: para fazer isso que pretende, de uma estudada em `ajax`, o ideal seria fazer essa validação no lado do cliente(JS), mas se for ESSENCIAL fazer a validação no lado do servidor(PHP), o ideal e usar `ajax`

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio estou elaborando um projeto para praticar o que venho estudando de forma autodidata, por isso a confusão em como fazer e o que utilizar para tal. Obrigado, vou estudar sim.

Comment: Se você pode habilitar ou desabilitar um recurso, este perde o titulo de **validação**. Jamais trate um recurso opcional do usuário como uma ferramenta de segurança.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

utilize a função [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php) dentro do atributo *value*:

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php
  echo filter_input('username', INPUT_POST);
?>">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="*******"/>
```

O código é equivalente à `echo $_POST['username']`, exceto pelas verificação para evitar erros da própria função.

**Importante:** não coloque no formulário a senha digitada pois pode expor os dados do usuário.

Comment: exatamente isso! Obrigado pela solução!

Answer (score 1):

Olá não precisa nem escrever php para isso, apenas coloque os campos `require=""` que se trata de um atributo do HTML 5 assim se não haver um dado inserido nem irá passar claro dependendo da versão do navegador:

```
<div id="form">
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="_100">
        <label for="username">Username: </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" require=""><br>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <label for="password" require="">Password: </label><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="*******" require=""><br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="">  
        <input type="submit" value="Entrar no Sistema">
    </div>
</form>
```

acredito que funcione e ficará com o código bem mais sucinto, agora caso queira não fazer dessa forma você poderá criar variáveis de sessão ou colocar em variáveis GET ou POST direcionando para mesma página, um exemplo de variável GET seria:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["nome"])) {
    $nome   = $_GET["nome"];
} else {
   nome="";
}
  //e em seu input

?>

<input value="<?=$nome;?>" type="text" name="nome">
```

Comment: Faltou mencionar que required e um atributo do `HTML5`

Comment: @André Martins a função `require` do HTML5 é funcional em versões de navegadores mais antigas? Estava evitando utiliza-la por ter lido que não era muito confiável.
Não seria necessário o uso de sessões, pois da forma como fiz os dados seriam enviados para a mesma página, mas como eu inseriria o dado no input do HTML? Onde eu deveria colocar `<?=variavelSessao?>` para que ele preenchesse o input?

Comment: resposta editada para te atender @Luan

Comment: **nem irá passar**? *Independente do navegador* teste isso: Clique em inspecionar elemento, encontre o input, remova o inútil `require`, submeta o form e verás um formulário sendo submetido.

Comment: @PapaCharlie não faça trauma no rapaz require é bom sim ruim são os navegadores como IE 6 e sua família.

Comment: @AndreMartins desculpe a ignorância? mas como pode dizer que os navegadores percursores de toda a internet são ruins?

Sua solução e eficaz, mas não eficiente

Comment: Eu instrui como 'burlar' a funcionalidade do `require` e você alega que é culpa dos navegadores antigos? Sua resposta não fornece uma solução de fato, e estou evitando negativar sua resposta sem que você tome conhecimento do erro que foi sua afirmação.

Comment: @PapaCharlie de fato, li alguns artigos relacionados e vi que o `require` não é confiável. @AndréMartins obrigado pela solução apresentada. Me deu uma visão de como funciona.

Comment: @PapaCharlie o que quis dizer é que não existe uma bala de prata e que não pode simplesmente dizer que o require é inútil.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio citei apenas o IE e sua família, agora se um desenvolvedor web disser que o IE 6 é bom, tem algo errado.